# openConnection api not working on android 6.0

Tags: android, json, get

I am trying to do a GET for json. It works well on android 5.0. but on my android 6.0 it is not working.

Here is code:

```
URL requestUrl = new URL(url);
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) requestUrl.openConnection();
result = convertInputStreamToString(con.getInputStream());
```

I can see from logs that requestUrl.openConnection() is not working and it is crashing with timeout.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: why -1? Please comment when doing so rather than just being over smart!!

Comment: I am aware of this but my app does not ask for any permission on 6.0. It just tries to get json from web and after some time, gives me I/O exception for timeout.

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace of the error in your logcat?